# R: 2 Different Computers: Getting "Error: All arguments must be named" in R

Tags: r, pair-programming

I am using the following command to change the column name in a `data frame`:

```
df <- rename(df, c("N1" = "N2"))
```

It works perfectly fine with `pair programming partner` but I keep getting the following error: "Error: All arguments must be named".

What could this error be caused by?

Comment: Please check the `dplyr` versions, R versions `rename(head(mtcars), c("mpg1" = "mpg"))` works fine with devel version of dplyr on R 4.0

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
rename(head(mtcars), c("mpg1" = "mpg"))
```